# Woocommerce pagination - prevent 301 redirect on page 1

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-301

Using latest versions of Wordpress & Woocommerce.

If I have 2 pages of products in my shop & I click **PAGE 1** in my pagination links, I get a 301 redirect that goes to **/shop**.

For SEO purposes I'd like to disable the 301 redirect & keep the link as it is in the pagination links i.e **/shop/page/1**

This seems to be the default behaviour in Woocommerce & it's not something my Shopkeeper theme is doing.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?  having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry I didn't. I got rid of the Woocommerce pagination & implemented a Javascript paging navigation instead!

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue with a site I'm building. Although you're asking to keep **/shop/page/1/** (with no 301) it is actually better to simply have **/shop/** as your page one. Otherwise you have two identical pages serving up the same content which Google is not fond of.

The approach I took was to change the output of the pagination to **NOT include /page/1/** in the link. This then removes the 301 as the link is correct to start with. To do this I used the filter `paginate_links`.

```
add_filter('paginate_links', function($link) {
    $pos = strpos($link, 'page/1/');
    if($pos !== false) {
        $link = substr($link, 0, $pos);
    }
    return $link;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Had a similar issue for vanilla WP blog site and this fix work as expected. I am not sure why this was not addressed in OOB WP code.

Comment: Will this code break when you reach page 10 aka /shop/page/10/? Seems like the second line of code should be "$pos = strpos($link, 'page/1/');" (note the added slash).

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to match only page 1. The answer by SaRiD will also match pages 10 - 19, 100+ etc as they all start with 1.

```
add_filter('paginate_links', function ($link) {
    return preg_replace('#page/1[^\d\w]#', '', $link);
});
```

Comment: Clean.. Stick this in your functions.php and BLAM! No more page 1 pagination 301 permanent redirect error!

Comment: A step in the right direction, but I'd say this is even more correct:
return preg_replace('#/page/1/#', '/', $link);

Comment: Escaping are only required if slashs are used as delimiters.

Comment: @scott8035 that assumes your urls use trailing slashes, which is not always true as they're optional in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by SaRiD will match all page numbers starting with a 1.

The answer by Christopher Geary uses preg_replace, which is unnecessary and should be avoided if possible.

[If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should use this function instead of preg_replace().](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

The following solution works with str_replace and only! if the trailing slash in WordPress permalinks is not disabled and there is no further path part /page/1/ in permalinks.

```
add_filter( 'paginate_links', function( $link ) {
    return str_replace( '/page/1/', '/', $link );
});
```

Thanks to SaRiD and Christopher Geary for your previous answers.

Comment: This doesn't work if the permalink structure excludes trailing slashes. This would not work against the examples provided in the original question.

Comment: @ChristopherGeary - Yes you are right, but I explicitly mentioned this condition in my answer. You could remove the trailing slash in $search and $replace parameters in this case.